# Can I open a dialog page without hiding the parent page in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two pages, one is a profile page and the other is a dialog page to comment on the profile page. The problem is on the profile page when the init() method is fired I update the DOM, but then once the dialog page closes init() is triggered again on the profile page. It wouldn't be a big deal but i fetch alot of data dynamically and don't want to do it again. Is there a way to some how just open the dialog page 'on top' of the profile page so to speak, or prevent the profile page from hiding in the first place?

```
<div data-role='page' id='profile'>

<div data-role='content'>
//dynamically fetch stuff for this div on pageInit()
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="ProfileComment">
<div data-role="header"><h4>Post comment</h4></div>
<div data-role="content">
    <textarea name="comment_data" id="comment_data"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="button_post" value="Post"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot The `pageinit` event fires on every jQuery Mobile page as the framework initializes the page. You can see the different custom events that jQuery Mobile exposes here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your pages are located in different documents. If this is the case then you can set the `data-dom-cache` attribute to `true` on the `data-role="page"` element for your `profile` page so when the user navigates away from it (to the `comment` page), it will remain in the DOM and the state of the page will be saved.

Here's the documentation for this setting: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-cache.html

By default, jQuery Mobile removes pages from the DOM after you navigate away from them (this is for external files only, not multi-page templates where all the pages are always in the DOM).